# Javascript :: How to get keys of associative array to array variable?

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, hash, associative-array

Let's have an associative array like this:

```
var aArray = {};
aArray.id = 'test';
aArray['x1'] = [1,2,3];
aArray['stackoverflow'] = 'What\'s up?';
aArray['x2'] = [4,5,6];
var keys = [];
for(var key in aArray) {
  if (aArray.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    keys.push(key);
  }
}
console.log(keys);
```

Is there any easy/short way how to get array of ***keys to array variable without loop***?

If so, additionally, is possible to apply some regular expression to key list to get just keys that match such pattern *(let's say* `/^x/`*)* without another loop?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is there any easy/short way how to get array of keys to array variable without loop..?

Yes, ECMAScript 5 defines [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to do this. (Also [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) to get even the non-enumerable ones.) Most moderns browser engines will probably have it, older ones won't, but it's easily shimmed (for instance, [this shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/) does).

> If so, additionally, is possible to apply some regular expression to key list to get just keys that match such pattern (let's say `/^x/`) without (another) loop?

No, no built-in functionality for that, but it's a fairly straightforward function to write:

```
function getKeys(obj, filter) {
    var name,
        result = [];

    for (name in obj) {
        if ((!filter || filter.test(name)) && obj.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            result[result.length] = name;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or building on `Object.keys` (and using ES2015+ features, because I'm writing this part in late 2020):

```
function getKeys(obj, filter) {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    return !filter ? keys : keys.filter(key => filter.test(key) && obj.hasOwnProperty(key));
}
```

Comment: +1 :: Yes, it is trivial, I am trying to use optimized way, as I am going to work with huge array, so that is only reason why I am trying to use some built-in functionality, if possible.

Comment: @Ωmega: Fair enough. Sadly, no, no built-in way that combines the steps. ES5 also has `Array#filter` which you could use in conjunction with `Object.keys`, but that would require making function calls back into your iterator function for each key, which would probably defeat the purpose.

Comment: Why is necessary to use `hasOwnProperty` when I create an object from scratch? What other "keys" may pop-up, if such object will have no internal variables and functions? Would not omitting of `hasOwnProperty` helps to speed-up the algorithm?

Comment: @Ωmega: If you're in complete control of the codebase, and you're using `{}` or `new Object` (preferably the former) to create the object, and you don't add any enumerable properties to `Object.prototype` (which you probably don't, it's a very bad idea), then yes, as an optimization you can leave out the `hasOwnProperty` because all properties of `Object.prototype` defined by the spec are non-enumerable. If you're going to use this on something created via a constructor function that has any enumerable properties on the prototype, then you'd want to leave it in.

Answer (score 15):

***In the year 2020***, every browser supports this back to IE9. This is the way to go.

JavaScript 1.8.5 has this functionality built in with **[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)**.  It returns an **array of all of the keys**. You could use a shim for non-supported browsers ([MDN has help on that too](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)).

As an example see this ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hD5cx/1/))...

```
var obj = { "cat" : "meow", "dog" : "woof"};
alert(Object.keys(obj)); // "cat,dog"
```

Comment: More to the point, [ECMAScript 5](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14) has this feature. Mozilla's JavaScript implements it, but so do others.

Comment: +1 :: Thank you for prompt response. Question is, if using this built-in functionality is faster - will test...

Comment: Here's a different one with a loop included of the keys.  http://jsperf.com/object-keys